# Accessing a CSV File outside python folder

Tags: python, file, csv, directory, forcing

So my files are the exact same size, with a row header and a column header. I need to add the values thare are in the rest of the cells besides the row and column header. This is the function I am using to do it:

```
def readStructured (filename):

    # Open the file
    fd = open (filename, 'rb')

    # CSV reader
    reader = csv.reader (fd , delimiter = ',')

    # Read data into memory
    data = []
    for row in reader:
        data.append (row)

    return data

def mergeStructured (data1, data2):

    # Empty array
    ret = []

    # Append the row header
    ret.append (data1[0])

    # For rows which are _not_ the row header,
    for rowIndex in range (1, len (data1)):
        row1 = data1[rowIndex]
        row2 = data2[rowIndex]

        # The row we are working on:
        current = []

        # Append the column header
        current.append (row1[0])

        # Now append the sum of the rest of the values
        for index in range (1, len(row1)):
            current.append (float (row1[index]) + float (row2[index]))

        # And put the result in our data
        ret.append (current)

    return ret

    And then I use this to call the functions:


data = readStructured('file1.csv')
data2 = readStructured('file2.csv')
y = mergeStructured(data, data2)
targetfile = open('testing.csv', 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(targetfile)
for row in y:
    writer.writerow(row)
targetfile.close()
```

This works perfectly. However, file1 and file2 are not in the python folder. The code I need to use is 
data = readStructured('C:\...\..\...\file1.csv')
data2 = readStructured('C:\...\..\...\file2.csv')

The files are the exact same. I opened the files in their C location and used save as to save them into my python folder. However, when I access the files in my C folder, my range for 1 to len(row1) goes out of range.

When I access the SAME files from my python folder, my range for 1 to len(row1) is 
perfect.

Any ideas?

Comment: why do you need ..\..\..\? Just `r"C:\file1.csv"` is enough.

Comment: the ... is specifying the subfolders that the files are actually in.

Comment: What do you mean when you say your range "goes out of range"?  What error are you getting?

Comment: @kevin I have no idea what you are trying to say with that.

Comment: So the real files are in a path like C:\folder1\subfolder1\subfolder2\subfolder3\file.csv.

Comment: The specific error is that it is trying to convert a empty cell into a float and add them in the mergeStructured function. So if the file has 20 columns of data, it is trying to access the 21st column. File "C:\Python25\Main.py", line 72, in mergeStructured current.append (float (row1[index]) + float (row2[index])) ValueError: empty string for float()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The files are the exact same. I opened the files in their C location and used save as to save them into my python folder.

It sounds to me like this might be the source of some invisible conversion. Adding an end-of-file character, or removing a trailing newline or something like that.  I wouldn't trust that the files are the same unless you copy the file.

Comment: I've copy pasted all the contents to a new excel sheet too and saved it as a csv file. I have noticed that it says that the file may contain features that are not compatible with CSV. Do you want to keep this workbook in this format? I've always just clicked yes but I think that this could possibly be altering the files somehow.

Comment: Alright yea when I copy the file it still runs into the error. It has something to do with the formatting of the csv file